# How View positioned behind ScrollView or ViewPager can receive click event?

Tags: android, layout, view, onclick, overlay

I have a View positioned behind `ScrollView` and need that View to be clickable. There is no problem in case of `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`. But in case of `ScrollView` or `ViewPager` my Veiw never get clicked.

Not working - iv1 not get clicked:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#888"
>

<TextView  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:text="Layer 1"
   android:textColor="#fff"
   android:gravity="center" />

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/list_button" />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#50ff0000"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#5000ff00">

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Layer 2"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/list_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Working - iv1 can be clecked:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#888"
>

<TextView  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:text="Layer 1"
   android:textColor="#fff"
   android:gravity="center" />

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/list_button" />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#50ff0000"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Layer 2"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/list_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it possible to to correct this?

Comment: your imageView "iv1" is not in the ScrollView. are you having problem including this layout in view pager?

Comment: I need iv1 to be behind ScrollView or ViewPager, not inside - layer 1: iv1, layer 2(above): ScrollView or ViewPager. I think that clicking is not possible because of both scroll and pager intercepts onToch* events and does not pass these events through hierarchy. ScrollView in my example is just for sample.

Comment: that's true, you have to over ride those, if you need click.

Comment: You may also try to bringToFront method to click it... But if you don't want it to be seen, you can set its visibility invisibile as default... so it'll not be seen by user but it can get clicked.